# How to configure webpack to not output minified code?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I recently started working with webpack and so far I like it. My only problem with it so far is, that it seems to only produce minified code for me.

This makes debugging my code in the browser a lot more difficult, and I have to rely on chromes prettify functionality.

Is there a way to configure this directly in webpack instead, something like setting the development mode to debug instead of production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set Webpack's mode. By default its value is `production`. You should set it to `development`.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development'
};
```

Alternatively you could look into [source maps.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)

Comment: That was surprisingly easy, but I just couldn't find any documentation. Thanks!